# NumberFormatException when converting String to Integer

Tags: java

I want to transform String array to Integer. I wrote this, but eclipse returns a error:

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("array_list.csv"));
    String everything = "";
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append('\n');
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        everything = sb.toString();
    } finally {
        br.close();
    }
    int firstArrLenght = everything.indexOf("]");
    int secondArrStartIndex = everything.lastIndexOf("[") + 1;
    int secondArrLenght = everything.lastIndexOf("]") - secondArrStartIndex;
    String[] firstStrArr = everything.substring(1, firstArrLenght).split(",");
    String[] secondStrArr = everything.substring(secondArrStartIndex, secondArrLenght).split(",");
```

And eclipse doesn't like these rows. I want to convert here String Array to Integer. Then I'll use the ints for the other logic.

```
    int[] firstArray = transformToInt(firstStrArr);
    int[] secondArray = transformToInt(secondStrArr);

}


private static int[] transformToInt(String[] arr) {
    int[] result = new int[arr.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        result[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[i].trim());
    }

    return result;
}
```

Exception stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
For input string: "" at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at Java.transformToInt(Java.java:38)
 at Java.main(Java.java:30)
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at Java.transformToInt(Java.java:38)
 at Java.main(Java.java:30)

Comment: Debug your code and you'll see how easy to find the bug!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

So the current String here you are trying to parse is empty in the line

```
  result[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[i].trim());
```

It's not possible to get an integer value from a empty string,That's what `exception` is saying.

What you can do is just check the emptiness of `String` before `parsing` it.